# efficient way to update object's attribute appropriately in list of objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have python class Ad. and contain list of Ad objects
`[<ad.Ad at 0x7fc07a4baaf0>,<ad.Ad at 0x7fc07a4ba970>,..., <ad.Ad at 0x7fc07a4a3490>]`

each object has following attributes:

```
print(ads[0].__dict__)
>>> {'ctr': 0.0004977702222791473,
     'name': 'A',
     'imps': 3895,
     'rewards': 1}
```

I have dataframe called upd_df that looks like this:

```
          reward  imps  CTR
Ad_name      
   A         3     10    0.3
   B         4     20    0.2
  ...
```

I want to update each Ad object with new CTR. What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

after update ads[0] now becomes, expect same for all objects:

```
print(ads[0].__dict__
>>> {'ctr':0.3,
     'name':'A',
     'imps':10,
     'reward':3}
```

Current methods is as follows.

```
for ad in ads:
    new = upd_df.loc[upd_df.index == ts_1.actions[0].name]
    new_ctr = new["CTR"].iloc[0]
    ad.ctr = new_ctr
```

However, hoping to find more efficient method if not vectorized method.

Comment: Move anything that does not vary with `ad` outside the loop.  `df.loc` and `iloc` can be expensive.  'vectorization' doesn't apply since that (normally) means applying compiled methods (usually `numpy`) to whole arrays (or dataframes).  You are changing a list of dict - and the dict objects have to be updated individually.  (There's nothing in `numpy` that operates on dict).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your dict to a dataframe, perform the substitution and then convert it back to a dict:

```py
ads_df = pd.DataFrame(ads).set_index('name')
upd_df = upd_df.rename(columns={'reward': 'rewards', 'CTR': 'ctr'}).set_index('Ad_name')

for col in ads_df.columns:
    ads_df.loc[upd_df.index, col] = upd_df[col]

ads_dict = list(ads_df.reset_index().transpose().to_dict().values())
print(ads_dict)
```